# Only display Woo Commerce sub-categories based on selected Parent Category in a wordpress widget sidebar

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress sidebar that I want to only display the children of the parent category. My structure is as follows

All Products > Parent Category > Children Categories

How do I get the sidebar to only display the Parent Category and Children Categories.

I read a solution to implement this code but I'm not sure where to put it inside the files.

```
<?php
if (is_category()) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&hierarchical=true&orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
    if($this_category !='<li>No categories</li>')
    {
     echo '<h3>Products</h3>'; 
     echo '<ul>'.$this_category.'</ul>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

These are screenshots from what my shop looks like and what I want.
[image: Current Look]

[image: Desired Look]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a shortcode in your theme's **functions.php** file as follows:

```
add_shortcode('child_category_list', 'get_child_category_list');

function get_child_category_list(){
    ob_start();
    
    // Only on product parent category pages
    if( is_product_category() ) {
        $parent = get_queried_object();

        $categories = get_term_children( $parent->term_id, 'product_cat' ); 
        if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) : 

            echo '<ul>';
            echo    '<li>';
            echo        '<a href="'.get_term_link ($parent->term_id, 'product_cat').'">'.$parent->name.'</a>';
            echo        '<ul>';
            foreach($categories as $category) :
                        $term = get_term( $category, 'product_cat' );
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'" >';
                        echo $term->name;
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
            endforeach;
            echo        '</ul>';
            echo    '<li>';
            echo '</ul>';

        endif;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Then, go to **Appearance > Widgets**, grab either **shortcode** or **text** widget into your sidebar and paste following shortecode:

```
[child_category_list]
```

[Tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U8m5.png) on localhost & its working fine.

Comment: Followed the answer completely and do not have anything appearing in the side bar. I did forget to mention I am using the WooCommerce plugin. Do I need to pass a parameter into the shortcode on the widget?

Comment: Make sure this particular sidebar is loading on category pages. Have you visited parent category pages to see whether it's showing or not?

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm using the Woo Commerce item categories and the Post categories. I'm restructuring the map and will update when I test more.

Comment: So to clarify, I want to sort by the child and parent items using the woo commerce categories, not the post categories.

Comment: @curiousSloth, i thought your code already working & you were asking where to add that code.. anyway, I've updated my code. This will show Parent & its child categories in the sidebar using the shortcode. Note that, it will only appear if a current category has any sub-categories exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I had to be on a Page instead of a Post in order for it to work.